# Building a list of string with a "one-line for" with str.split

Tags: python

it seems to be a very basic question but I can't find an answer.

I'm trying to build a list of strings from a split on a bigger string.

```
input = 'I#have#a#problem'
result = [s for s in input.split('#')]
>>> ['I', 'have', 'a', 'problem']
```

That works perfectly. The problem is, sometimes the input is not a string, but None. To avoid the python error `AttributeError: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`, I tried to add an `if` statement, but that doesn't do anything to prevent the error.

```
input = None
result = [s for s in input.split('#') if input]
>>> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Is there a way to do that while keeping the one-liner ?

Thanks

Comment: That's for filtering items in the for statement. Try parenthesizing differently: `[s for s in input.split('#')] if input else None`

Comment: Also, you should really use `if input is not None else None` - see [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51)

Comment: And a correction to the comment above, the list comprehension isn't really needed, because split returns a list already. So `input.split('#') if input else None`.

Comment: @SiHa That's also a good point, unless you have such inputs that they can be *falsy* and you want the result to still be None.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

Comment: @Felix True, although, I would suggest that if that's possible you should be refactoring your code.

Comment: @SiHa Fair enough :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is no need to do this :
`[s for s in input.split('#')]`
because split() returns already a list
`input.split('#')` is enough
But for the None issue, here is my suggestion :

```py
result = inputStr.split('#') if inputStr else None
```

And here we go :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
if input: result = input.split("#")
```

This should work. No need to put brackets!
Or, if you want to define result anyway:

```
result = input.split("#") if input else None
```

Comment: Note that result is not defined after doing this if the input is none. Could be dangerous.

Comment: Also, one line ifs like this are considered bad style in Python.

Comment: Well, that's what the user asked, a one-line solution

Comment: True. But that's no reason to suggest suboptimal solutions. Look at my comment though, which has the generally accepted one-line if *with* an else statement. I don't mean to belittle your answer, but I believe it could be done better.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `input` as variable name, return a `else None` if it is None (`input` is `Input` here):

```
[[s for s in Input.split('#')] if Input else None]
```

Another list Comprehension less edition:

```
if Input: result = Input.split("#")
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the latter solution. See my comments in the other answer.